# How to take dynamic datatype in dictionary object

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I came up with situation where I am taking value from user in the form of querystring.
Name of first 2 parameter is fix,so name name of querystring is fix.After these 2 parameter,user may enter or may not enter any parameter.Parameter count can be from 1 to many and vary in datatype.

```
 Ex: sitename/sample.aspx?username=''&userid=''&Date=
 Ex: sitename/sample.aspx?username=''&userid=''&Date=&amount=
```

That's why I created dictionary object and storing key and value of dynamic querystring into it(not username and userid).

```
Dictionary<string, string> queryStringValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
{
    queryStringValues.Add(key, Request.QueryString[key]);
}
```

Here I have created dictionary of `<string,string>` .But my key must be `string` and value may not `string`. It can be `int`,`date` .How to take that?

At last I want to check datatype of value? How to do that?

Comment: Does it have to be a `Dictionary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could  use `Dictionary` with objects.

```
Dictionary<string, object> queryStringValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

Note, after that ou should cast your objects to knwon type , something as:

```
queryStringValues.Add("2", true);
```

...

```
var q = queryStringValues["2"];
if (q is bool)
{
    var r = !(bool)q;
}
```

Comment: Without proper conversion it wont work as intended. [result is here](http://rextester.com/SSWI26146)

Comment: @m.rogalski i have fixed your example:  http://rextester.com/CPYPG68650  You had two strings, not string and bool.

Comment: `Request.QueryString[key]` will return `string` not `bool` or `object`. You can read about that in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Query string as the name says it's a `string` ( a collection of key value pair that consists of 2 strings ( key and value ) ) so basically you cannot know for sure if value of `Date` would be convertible to `DateTime` object.

You can though make something like factory ( which I've done few months ago ) to pair `key` with different `Type`.

To explain this in more detail :

```
public static class Factory
{
    static Dictionary<string, Type> _fac = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    public static void Assign<T>(string key)
    {
        if(_fac.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            if(_fac[key] != typeof(T)) _fac[key] = typeof(T);
        }
        else 
        {
            _fac.Add(key, typeof(T));
        }
    }

    public static object Retrieve(string key, string value)
    {
        if(_fac.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            if(_fac[key] == typeof(string))
                return value;

            TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(_fac[key]);
            if(converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string))
                return converter.ConvertFromString(value);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Type TypeFor(string key)
    {
        if(_fac.ContainsKey(key))
            return _fac[key];

        return null;
    }
}
```

To use this simply do something like :

```
Factory.Assign<DateTime>("date");

// later on, you can retrieve value using this:
// assume query is "Date=01/01/2001"
Dictionary<string, object> queryStringValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys) 
{
    queryStringValues.Add(key, Factory.Retrieve(key, Request.QueryString[key]));
}
```